# Copy all text from webbrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, browser

Is it possible to scrape all the text from a site that was navigated to by `WebBrowser` control without looking at the source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the [`DocumentText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bbc4s4h(v=vs.110).aspx) property or the WebBrowser control.

This property is what holds the HTML of the site you have navigated to.

**Update:** (following comments)

If you want to *parse* the HTML and get the text parts of it, I suggest you use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home).

Comment: oded, i do not want to look at the html, i only want to look at the text that the user sees

Comment: no i dont want to parse the html, i just want the same result as if you hit ctrl A and copy and paste all the text

Comment: Um. That's what you will get by _parsing_ the HTML.

Answer (score 7):

David Walker's method is great when one don't need any info from the header nor non main part of the webpage. if one need something outside inner text, there is only two options, one is to parse with "getElement".
the other one is issue commands (Document.ExecCommand) to webbrowser to select all and copy to clipboard:

```
wb.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
wb.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
```

then finally string content=clipboard.getText();

Please note the spelling and syntax may not be correct, I'm recalling from my memory

Answer (score 5):

```
string browserContents = webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerText;
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me onto the scent David. If you want to preserve the formatting like I do, use webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml;