# How to get HTML from WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, wpf

There are loads of posts similar to this.

[How to get rendered html (processed by Javascript) in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333973/how-to-get-rendered-html-processed-by-javascript-in-webbrowser-control) suggests to use something like

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].OuterHtml;
```

`Document` is treated as an object, I have no option to use `GetElementsByTagName`

[Copy all text from webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637192/copy-all-text-from-webbrowser-control) suggests to use `DocumentText`

I have `Document` but no `DocumentText`

That post also suggests `webBrowser.Document.Body.InnerText;`

I have the option to use `webBrowser.Document` but that is it. For some reason `webBrowser.Document` is an object and as such I can't access these methods.

[Getting the HTML source through the WebBrowser control in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164733/getting-the-html-source-through-the-webbrowser-control-in-c-sharp) also suggests using `DocumentStream`. Again, I don't have that.

I'm doing this in a WPF application and using `WebBrowser` from `System.Windows.Controls`

All I'm trying to is read the rendered HTML from the web page.

My code

```
public void Begin(WebBrowser wb)
{
   this._wb = wb;
   _wb.Navigated += _wb_Navigated;
   _wb.Navigate("myUrl");
}

private void _wb_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var html = _wb.Document;//this is where I need help
}
```

Comment: _wb.DocumentText ?

Comment: @JuryGolubev, look at the 6th line down in my post. I already explained it's not there as an option in intellisense :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972874/how-can-i-get-an-htmlelementcollection-from-a-wpf-webbrowser

Comment: @Equalsk, actually, this can be marked as a dupe of that. Sorry, I spent 2 days looking and never saw that post

Comment: Your username is appropriate then ;-)

Comment: I'm unable to test it but I'm sure your code should be `((mshtml.HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document).GetElementsByTag‌​Name("HTML")[0].Oute‌​rHtml;`

Comment: Pretty much @Equalsk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your samples refer to the [WinForms-WebBrowserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx).
Add a reference to [Microsoft.mshtml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317(v=vs.85).aspx) (via add-reference dialog->search) to your project.

Cast the [Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.document(v=vs.110).aspx)-Property to

> HTMLDocument

in order to access methods and properties (as stated on MSDN).

See also my [GitHub-Sample](https://github.com/earloc/WPF_WebBrowser_Sample/blob/master/MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```
private void WebBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) {
    var document = (HTMLDocument)_Browser.Document;
     _Html.Text = document.body.outerHTML;
}
```

Comment: If you do not need to actually render the html on the screen, you may be better off using [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)